# Bootsrap Form Group & Input Group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been playing with the below code for hours. Essentially, I'd like a small input field with the two buttons next to it! I'm unable to get the buttons to line up with the text field, and my combination of classes seems to have shrunk the text field drastically.

What's missing/needs changing for the buttons to appear correctly alongside the text field?

[image]

```
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="CueIn">Cue In</label>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  id="CueIn" name="CueIn" value="<?php if(isset($id3_tags_mAirList_CueIn)) { echo $id3_tags_mAirList_CueIn; } ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnSet_CueIn" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnGo_CueIn" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="Ramp1">Ramp 1</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ramp1" name="Ramp1" value="<?php if(isset($id3_tags_mAirList_Ramp1)) { echo $id3_tags_mAirList_Ramp1; } ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnSet_Ramp1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnGo_Ramp1" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="Ramp2">Ramp 2</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ramp2" name="Ramp2" value="<?php if(isset($id3_tags_mAirList_Ramp2)) { echo $id3_tags_mAirList_Ramp2; } ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnSet_Ramp1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnGo_Ramp1" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="Ramp3">Ramp 3</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ramp3" name="Ramp3" value="<?php if(isset($id3_tags_mAirList_Ramp3)) { echo $id3_tags_mAirList_Ramp3; } ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnSet_Ramp1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnGo_Ramp1" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="Outro">Outro</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Outro" name="Outro" value="<?php if(isset($id3_tags_mAirList_Outro)) { echo $id3_tags_mAirList_Outro; } ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnSet_Ramp1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnGo_Ramp1" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="StartNext">Start Next</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="StartNext" name="StartNext" value="<?php if(isset($id3_tags_mAirList_StartNext)) { echo $id3_tags_mAirList_StartNext; } ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnSet_Ramp1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnGo_Ramp1" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3">
        <label for="CueOut">Cue Out</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="CueOut" name="CueOut" value="<?php if(isset($id3_tags_mAirList_CueOut)) { echo $id3_tags_mAirList_CueOut; } ?>">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnSet_Ramp1" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-label="Left Align" aria-hidden="true" id="btnGo_Ramp1" />
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `.input-group-addon { padding: 0px 2px; }`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="padding: 100px 100px 10px;">
   <form class="bs-example bs-example-form" role="form">
      <div class="input-group">
         <input type="text" class="form-control">
         <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
         <span class="input-group-addon">.00</span>
      </div>
   </form>
</div>
```